# SQL GROUP BY 3 columns not working

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

I have a table in an Oracle database which stores requests to a web app. The structure is something like:

```
---------------------------------------
DATETIME    | USERID     | ACTION
---------------------------------------
```

I would like to build a query that aggregates these requests by date, user, and action for the last 30 days. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT
  DATETIME,
  USERID, 
  ACTION,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  USER_ACTIVITY
WHERE
  DATETIME > SYSDATE - 30
GROUP BY 
  DATETIME,
  USERID, 
  ACTION
ORDER BY 
  DATETIME DESC,
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

When I run this I get a lot of duplicate rows, like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
DATETIME    | USERID     | ACTION     | COUNT   
--------------------------------------------------
14-NOV-14     user1        update       2
14-NOV-14     user1        update       1
14-NOV-14     user2        update       3
14-NOV-14     user1        update       1
```

Does anyone know why these aren't getting rolled up into a single count for each distinct combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have a time component on the date.  Try this:

```
SELECT trunc(DATETIME) as date, USERID, ACTION, COUNT(*)
FROM USER_ACTIVITY
WHERE DATETIME > SYSDATE - 30
GROUP BY trunc(DATETIME), USERID,  ACTION
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

You might want to apply the same idea to the `where` clause as well, unless you want partial days:

```
SELECT trunc(DATETIME) as date, USERID, ACTION, COUNT(*)
FROM USER_ACTIVITY
WHERE DATETIME > trunc(SYSDATE) - 30
GROUP BY trunc(DATETIME), USERID,  ACTION
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC, COUNT(*) DESC;
```